# How to install a C compiler on Linux?

Tags: software-installation, compiler

I need to install a compiler in Linux. First of all, some system information:

```
-bash-3.2$ uname -a
Linux axentraserver.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com 2.6.31.8 #97 Thu Sep 12 10:38:00 EDT 2013 armv5tel armv5tel armv5tel GNU/Linux
```

This Linux version is hosted on a NAS.

The problem is that no package manager is installed.

```
bash-3.2# ./configure --prefix=/usr
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/administrator/Test/m4-1.4.17':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

I'm trying to install GNU m4, which is needed for the next package. There is no `yum`, `apt-get` or anything similar.

So, how can I install a C compiler manually?

Comment: Don't you have any *more distribution-specific* information to provide? "Linux" doesn't really help much... You could try installing `gcc` (GNU C Compiler), yet I don't know how its `configure` script would end...

Comment: Why do you want to install `gcc` on that particular system? Could you not build whatever it is you want to build on another system (with a package manager etc.) and copy the binaries across?

Comment: @StephenKitt Your right, I can´t build anything.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith  'bash-3.2# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.31.8 (mostafah@es5x86.axentra.com) (gcc version 4.3.2 (sdk3.3-ct-ng-1.4.1) ) #97 Thu Sep 12 10:38:00 EDT 2013
bash-3.2# cat /etc/*release
Version     2.0.0.114
DistName    hipserv2_medion
VersionName 2.9
CentralServer lifecloudmedion.com
Serial xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
Subdomain xxxxXXXX
HipServ'

Comment: @JohnWHSmith The 'configure' script from the 'gcc' ends up with the same error.

Comment: To save everyone else the pain: This is [Axentra HipServ2, which is based upon Red Hat Enterprise Linux](http://www.axentra.com/axentra-launches-hipserv-2-0-the-next-generation-home-server-platform-at-ces-2009).

Answer (score 1):

Is that a Medion router or NAS?

I think your best choice (if nobody has already packaged a C/C++ compiler for direct unpack + use) is to crosscompile your program in a full Linux box and then copy the resulting binaries to your system.

Maybe you could use crossgc and crosstool-ng to compile your program.

Comment: I complied the binaries on a Ubuntu Linux. Now i get `cannot execute binary file`

Comment: It seems that you have compiled it for your Linux box architecture (i386 or x86_64). You cannot generate an "intel" binary: you have to cross compile for the ARMV5TEL architecture. Cross compiling means that you build a binary for a different architecture (the "target machine") than the architecture in the "compiling machine". Run "file the-binary" to see what architecture you used for the compiling. Use a cross-compiler (crossgcc,  crostools-ng) to crosscompile the sources.